# Is it possible to export keyframes with constant interpolation to FBX?

Tags: animation, export, unity

I'd like to export an animation with Constant interpolation (as opposed to Linear or Bezier) to FBX. If I export a sample animation to FBX, then import it back into Blender, the keyframes are imported with Linear interpolation. I'm not sure whether this is due to a limitation of the FBX file format or a limitation of Blender's FBX exporter and/or importer.

Is it even possible to specify keyframe interpolation modes in FBX?

Comment: For me export/import to fbx using blender keeps constant interp, bezier interp imports with keyframes every frame. Do you have the bake animation option enabled when exporting?

Comment: @sambler Yes, Bake Animation is checked. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @sambler I'm not exactly sure what the Bake Animation options does and the Blender User's Manual literally says "TODO", haha

Comment: Each fcurve should get baked into a keyframe for each frame. For constant interp it seems to only export a keyframe for each change in value, for bezier that becomes a keyframe for each frame.

Comment: After some investigation (and reading through source code), I discovered that the FBX importer and exporter only support Linear interpolation. When you choose the Bake Animation option with Constant interpolation, it creates keyframes that give the illusion of constant interpolation. However, it uses linear interpolation in between frames. Not normally a problem, but it is in my scenario where all of my keyframes last only a single frame. It can cause problems depending on how other programs sample the keyframes.